# Lost coins after approve on Uniswap

Tags: uniswap, usdt

I hope someone can help me.

I wanted to swap my USDT for ShopX on Uniswap. I had my USDT in my metamask wallet and was connected on Uniswap. I had to approve so that I could swap. Appently I made a mistake, now my USDT is gone. Hopefully someone can help me understand what happened and if I am lucky how to solve it.
Thanks for any help!

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9fc1450990cf7bcbedbd776c314e60bb9e35274ef322fb83a13e45f90c933190

Greetings,
Sebas

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, it appears that you made the approval to a scammer address (0xc9Fc874AebFeFb1CaD9d24c07Faf990021A72f62), not the Uniswap router as it should have been. The USDT were transferred to his account seconds later.

My guess is that you made the approval on a fake Uniswap website setup by the scammer.

You can report the address on etherscan to help others, but your tokens are lost.

Comment: Well that sucks big time.
Thanks for taking the time to check it out. Too bad that the tokens are lost. Ofcourse I will report the address and hopefully help others.

Comment: Do you remember what website you used? Maybe you can find it in your browser history.

Answer (score 0):

the exchange that is correct or trusted also gives itself spender privilege's lasting forever. you cant remove it but you can change the amount approved to zero. what i dont know is if it gave them the private keys and if they can get back in.

this web site is where to fix approved amounts.

https://tac.dappstar.io/#/address

my personal experience was at extreme cost and there will be no end for fraud.